# Azure Logic App Change Schedule Recurrence

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have an Azure Logic App that is triggered on Recurrence Schedule every 10 minutes, then sends a SMS to me if a particular condition is true. Ideally, after the SMS is actioned, I want it to delay the next Recurrence Schedule by 1 hour. I've tried the Delay action but that only delays the next action in this particular job. I want it to change the schedule time of the next job, so that I don't keep receiving the same SMS every 10 minutes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the logic app run with only one instance. By default, Logic App instances run at the same time, or in parallel. So although you add a delay action to delay 1 hour, the other instance will be triggered next minute normally. You need to limit the logic app with only one instance, click the "**...**" button in the upper right corner of your "**Recurrence**" trigger and click "**Settings**".
[image]

Then enable "**Concurrency Control limit**" and set the value of "**Degree of Parallelism**" to `1`
[image]

After that, the logic app can just run with one instance. If there is a delay action in previous running instance hasn't completed, the next running instance can not be triggered.